# Wicket 7 static web resources folder mount

Tags: java, html, resources, wicket

I'm using wicket 7.

My Package-Structure looks like:

src/main/java <- webapp + pages

src/main/resources

src/main/webapp/css

src/main/webapp/images <-images

I want to create img elements in my html pages referencing static images, without creating Image object on the java side all the time.

I just want to use something like this:

```
<img src="images/add.png">
```

I've tried a lot of ways but I can't seem to find the best way to **mount** the resource folder globally in Wicket 7.

Anyone know of a simple way of donig this?

Comment: Java side: `new Image("imageId", new ContextRelativeResource("/images/source");`. HTML side `<img wicket:id="imageId"></img>`

Comment: Thanks but this is exactly what I want to avoid, creating a wicket entity for every single image.

Comment: @PeterJaloveczki did you ever figure this out?